# Late-rename file after commit in git

Tags: git, git-mv

Someone changed a file name and its content in a way that git was unable to detect that it was the same file.

They also didn't use `git mv`, so when I got the pull request I saw a new file being added and an old file being deleted, which makes it impracticable for reviewing.

Being a nice guy I pulled their code and tried to do a *late* `git mv`, so I'd be able to add a commit to their pull request and see things beautifully on Github review page, but that didn't work.

Is there a way to do a posthumous rename of a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git doesn't track file identity:  there's nothing in the repository that says that file `bar` in revision *n* was renamed/copied/moved from file `foo` in revision (*n*-1).  Doing `git mv` is the same as doing plain `mv` followed by `git add` on the new name and `git rm` on the old.  The repository just stores a snapshot of the directory tree at each commit, and it's up to the tools *examining* the repository to make decisions about how the files in different commits relate to each other.

When you're looking at the revision history and git says a file was moved or renamed, it's determining that locally, as a guess based on the similarity of the old and new files' contents.  Many git commands support a `-M` option that lets you specify the similarity threshold for deciding that a delete and an add in the same commit should be regarded as a rename.  The default threshold is 50%.

If you want git to treat the change as a rename by default, without having to specify a lower `-M` threshold every time you examine the repository, you can split the change into two commits:  one to change the contents while keeping the name, and one to rename the file while keeping the contents unchanged (or at least, less than 50% changed).

Doing this "posthumously" will, of course, require resetting the branch head to before the old commit, replacing it with the two new commits, force-pushing, and contacting anyone who might have pulled the original version to let them know you've changed history.  (This is no different from making any other kind of change to a commit that's been published to others.)

Comment: and I suppose github doesn't let me somehow specify the `-M` to their code comparison page, right?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I don't use github much.

Comment: @Roberto - A quick browse through https://github.com/tiimgreen/github-cheat-sheet didn't turn up anything, but maybe you'll have better luck than I did. And if you didn't already know about that cheat sheet, well, glad I could help. :-)